# Alterar parte de todos os registros de duas colunas através de uma referência

Tags: sql

Boa noite, pessoal! Sou [noob](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newbie) em `SQL` e pretendo me esforçar para aprender mais com a ajuda de vocês.

**Detalhes:**

- As colunas pertencem a mesma tabela
- A parte do registro a ser retirado é comum em todas as rows, ou seja, essa seria a referência que usaria para não alterar informações erradas!

---

### CONSULTA:

```
ID - PARAMS                                                          - LAYERS 
1 / {"image":"http:\/\/www.meussite.com.br\/imagens_a\/banner1.png"} /  ....
2 / {"image":"http:\/\/www.meussite.com.br\/imagens_c\/banner2.png"} /  ....
3 / {"image":"http:\/\/www.meussite.com.br\/imagens_b\/banner3.png"} /  ....
...
```

Como eu substituo esse valor `www.meussite.com.br`, que está tanto na coluna `PARAMS` quanto na coluna `LAYERS` por este: `www.meunovosite.com.br`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o comando `UPDATE` para atualizar sua tabela, e a função `REPLACE` para substituir os valores:

```
UPDATE nome_tabela
SET params = REPLACE(params, 'www.meussite.com.br', 'www.meunovosite.com.br'),
    layers = REPLACE(layers, 'www.meussite.com.br', 'www.meunovosite.com.br');
```

Comment: Vou testar, se der errado, te mato :)

Comment: eUUREECAA, valeu man. Você se salvou.

Comment: hahah :) @Lollipop